# One more question about sign transaction on cold-wallet node via wallet-rpc

Tags: transfer

I need to make a transfer on hot-wallet (view-only) and sign it on my offline wallet(cold-wallet) via wallet-rpc

And then send it to blockchain

It possible?
I know how it can be done through a wallet-cli and unsigned_tx file

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18083/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"transfer","params":{"destinations":[{"amount":1000,"address":"9uUr8urCW73Hf1S2PxDkmKBk8wRujbSNuVgusyUDGv5seSjbKwDATafCXAmbWd8cWHghhzF2J4hpGLXEkUkxHCT35A4VaU3"}],"mixin":1,"get_tx_key": true}}' -H 'Content-Type:application/json'
{
  "error": {
    "code": -4,
    "message": "transaction was rejected by daemon"
  },
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
```

with `do_not_relay` parameter it returns:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18083/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"transfer","params":{"destiations":[{"amount":1000,"address":"9uUr8urCW73Hf1S2PxDkmKBk8wRujbSNuVgusyUDGv5seSjbKwDATafCXAmbWd8cWHghhzF2J4hpGLXEkUkxHCT35A4VaU3"}],"mixin":1,"get_tx_key": true, "do_not_relay":true}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "amount": 1000,
    "fee": 851850000,
    "multisig_txset": "",
    "tx_blob": "",
    "tx_hash": "f7afba7ccb8e859a7600927053759d51f3904add1ba5217329a4a402d48fa6c5",
    "tx_key": "f9a932f872f28b1c1be19342c84e59fbe244b6e902430daf22dbd8b2f0eb4100",
    "tx_metadata": ""
  }
```

Can anyone help me with create and sign transfer with wallet-rpc??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `transfer` or `transfer_split` on a hot wallet, you'll get data back in the `unsigned_txset` field. This was not yet present when you posted your question.

This `unsigned_txset` data can then be conveyed to the cold wallet, which signs it with `sign_transfer`, which gives you back a signed `unsigned_txset` field.

In turn, this is conveyed to the hot wallet, which then uses `submit_transfer` with that data.